# Principle of induction variant

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

Let $a\leq b$ be two natural numbers. Let $P(n)$ be some statement involving $n$. Does the formula
$$P(b)\ \land\ (\forall n)(a\leq n<b\ \land\ (\forall m)(n<m\implies P(m))\implies P(n))$$
imply
$$(\forall n)(n\in[a,b]\implies P(n))?$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: put $Q(n) \equiv P(b - n) \lor n > b - a$ and apply what is called [course of values, or complete or strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to $Q(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

In
$P(b)\ \land\ (\forall n)(a\leq n<b\ \land\ (\forall m)(n<m\implies P(m))\implies P(n))
$
you have
$(\forall m)(n<m\implies P(m))
$.

This implies unbounded $m$.

Do you mean
$(\forall m)(n>m\implies P(m))
$?